# Can't read a file using '.read()' function , getting an error

Tags: python

Can't read a file using '.read()' function , getting an error

```
with open(r'‪D:\Programing work\Python projects\AOTS\wdutom.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    ac=f.read()


print(ac)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programing work\Python projects\AOTS\exe.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open(r'‪D:\Programing work\Python projects\AOTS\wdutom.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:       
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aD:\\Programing work\\Python projects\\AOTS\\wdutom.txt'
```

content of file:

[image]

Comment: Try: `with open(filename, encoding="utf-8") as f:`

Comment: This new error is commoing    :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programing work\Python projects\AOTS\exe.py", line 1, in <module>
    with open('‪D:\Programing work\Python projects\AOTS\wdutom.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\u202aD:\\Programing work\\Python projects\\AOTS\\wdutom.txt'

Comment: Can you share what is the content of the file?

Comment: You have to combine it with a raw string: `with open(r"D:\Programing work\Python projects\AOTS\wdutom.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:` you have a byte in front of the filename string: `'\u202aD:\\Programing ...` Alternatively, try to write out the whole file path on your keyboard not copying it from somewhere else.

Comment: the content is way to large to come in coment

Comment: Please [edit] the question an include the content of the file

Comment: @leo, again from what you have posted, try to write out the full path directly in the code. You have `'\u202aD:\\Programing` in front of your filepath, which typically indicates you have copied the filepath from somewhere and pasted it directly into your code.

Comment: Here's [another question with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68683348/oserrorerrno-22-invalid-argument-u202ac-users-me-document-babyname-cs#comment121381006_68683348) I agree with @user56700; this is probably caused by copying and pasting the filename from somewhere and getting an invisible character (left-to-right embedding mark -- is the OP using a right-to-left language, by any chance?) by mistake.

Comment: @TurePålsson yeah you are 100% on that one, totally forgot about that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open(r'D:\Programing work\Python projects\AOTS\wdutom.txt') as f:
    ac=f.read()
print(ac)
```

You can use `r` in the beginning